# Carthage update - Task failed with exit code 65

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, carthage

I have 2 versions of Xcode installed, 8.3.2 and 8.2.1.

I'm working on a project that was written in Swift 2 and installed few third-party's via Carthage.
After pulling branch I did `carthage update` : then I got this error:

```
$ carthage update
*** Fetching SwiftyJSON
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Fetching Reachability.swift
*** Fetching AlamofireImage
*** Checking out Alamofire at "3.5.1"
*** Checking out AlamofireImage at "2.5.0"
*** Checking out Reachability.swift at "v2.4"
*** Checking out SwiftyJSON at "54017d514a87b2b855b407131292c510cdeb65f8"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/6s/5fm277hs03qb526nqykyplk40000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.JxFgDC.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire watchOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/maor/myProj/myProj/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Alamofire.xcworkspace -scheme Alamofire\ watchOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/maor/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/Alamofire/3.5.1 -sdk watchos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean build

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/6s/5fm277hs03qb526nqykyplk40000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.JxFgDC.log
```

---

> part of carthage-xcodebuild.JxFgDC.log

```
=== CLEAN TARGET Alamofire watchOS OF PROJECT Alamofire WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
=== BUILD TARGET Alamofire watchOS OF PROJECT Alamofire WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after removing Xcode 8.3.2 the problem solved

Comment: Hi, what's the problem with Xcode 8.3.2? It's the newest Xcoder version now.

Comment: @vietstone  I guess the problem was with two Xcode's installed.. maybe something went wrong with the paths.. after uninstalling 8.3.2 it solved.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue while updating the carthage.

```
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 65: ..... This usually indicates that the project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcode build log for more details: /var/folders/np/1zqyzhbn4ljcb8fmdkz5y90h0000gq/T/carthage-xcodebuild.WE9DXB.log
```

This was due to the incorrect Xcode version pointed to the command-line tool. I updated the version and the issue is fixed. You can change it from the Xcode preference This way you can keep multiple Xcode with your machine. [image: Xcode Preference]

Answer (score 3):

If you install two versions of xcode, you can do as list:
excute shell: xcode-select -s (path of your xcode.app)

Comment: This turned out to be the key for me.  With a recently-installed new version of Xcode, I needed to make sure `xcode-select` was pointed at the correct toolchain.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a new device you're pulling the changes to: run `carthage bootstrap` to install according to the [docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#running-a-project-that-uses-carthage)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the version of the cocoapods library that you want to use, it's not compatible with your Xcode version, so make sure to give the version of the library. For example:
`github "danielgindi/Charts`" to `github "danielgindi/Charts" ~> 3.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same error after trying to pull stuff in for a downloaded demo project. Build was failing for me because I did not set any valid signing identities in the Xcode project before trying to perform the carthage update command in Terminal.