# Build Failed Task failed with exit code 65

Tags: swift, carthage, swinject

I am working on a project that uses Carthage, it’s been a couple of months since the last time the project was opened. Now I am trying to move dependencies to `.xcframeworks` because with the old `.framework`, it wasn’t working. I encountered various errors and fixed them but there’s one dependency that I can’t fix,   SwinjectStoryboard .

I tried using [this workaround](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md) and [setting command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831086/carthage-update-task-failed-with-exit-code-65)

[image]

I have also tried creating an empty project with only `Swinject` and `SwinjectStoryboard` dependency

but still, my build is failing with the following message

> Build Failed  Task failed with exit code 65:  /usr/bin/xcrun
> xcodebuild -project
> /Users/abu/Developer/xcframework_2/Carthage/Checkouts/SwinjectStoryboard/SwinjectStoryboard.xcodeproj
> -scheme SwinjectStoryboard-iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/abu/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.5_12E262/SwinjectStoryboard/2.2.0
> -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive VALIDATE_WORKSPACE=NO
> -archivePath /var/folders/g9/rjxzfx7d2s51_sr6stdkpc5c0000gn/T/SwinjectStoryboard
> SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO
> CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO
> FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=$(inherited)
> /var/folders/g9/rjxzfx7d2s51_sr6stdkpc5c0000gn/T/carthage-xcframework-HTlC
> (launched in
> /Users/abu/Developer/xcframework_2/Carthage/Checkouts/SwinjectStoryboard)
>
> This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please
> check the xcodebuild log for more details:
> /var/folders/g9/rjxzfx7d2s51_sr6stdkpc5c0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.Tafjce.log

I am running the following command to build the dependencies

`carthage.sh update --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS`

here's my contents of my Cartfile

> github "Swinject/Swinject"
>
> github "Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard"

I am stuck on this problem for a couple of days now and would appreciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carthage update - Task failed with exit code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831086/carthage-update-task-failed-with-exit-code-65)

Comment: yeah I have tried it, the same error

Comment: @Abdurakhmon, did you solve this?

Comment: the problem was I was using latest xcode version and the crash was happening because of that

Comment: @Abdurakhmon How you have solved it? Please share steps?

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it, I moved to another project

Comment: @MayurShrivas Have you solved it ?

Comment: The problem was I was using latest Xcode version and the crash was happening because of that, I haven't fixed the issue, I moved to another project

Comment: @ankitjaiswal, I've moved that dependency to SPM which solved the problem.